# How to add an ordinal data column based on prices to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, ordinal-classification

I have a dataset of used cars, there is a column of prices in the dataset. I want to introduce a new **ordinal** column with the values (high, medium, and low) considering the prices of cars like so:

| price | ordinal |
| --- | --- |
| higher than 20,000 | high |
| 10,000-20,000 | medium |
| below 10,000 | low |

Dataset:
[image: screenshot of dataset]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

```
df["ordinal"] = df["price"].apply(lambda x: "high" if x > 20000 else "low" if x < 10000 else "medium")
```

what is `apply`? `apply` is a method that apply it's first paramater (lambda) on all rows (or something else depends on second parameter).

but, there, and what is our function (lambda):

it just has one parameter (x) and check one `if-else`, we can rewite it again:

```
if x > 20000:
    return "high"
else:
    if x < 10000:
        return "low"
    else:
        return "medium"
```

we refer to this type of `if-else` as `ternary statement` or `one-line-if-else`

`what-must-do-if-statement-is-true` `if` `statement` `else` `what-must-do-if-statement-is-false`

and you can define another ternary in `what-must-do-if-statement-is-false` part like above,

and in `what-must-do-if-statement-is-true` part, using parentheses:
`(another-ternary)` `if` `statement` `else` `what-must-do-if-statement-is-false`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `cut`

```
df['ordinal'] = pd.cut(df['price'],
                       [0,10000,20000,np.Inf],
                       labels = ['Low','Medium','High'])
```